# Don't render a part of the input element value string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'd like to hide a bit of the value string like:

```
<input type="submit" name="approve" id="approveButton" value="Approve/@a.Id" class="btn btn-info btn-label"/>
```

`/@a.id` shouldn't be displayed

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: What is `a`? Have you tried `value="Approve/@(a.Id)"`? What is your desired `submit` value that you wish to display - could you provide an example?

Comment: @GeoffJames I'm iterating through a list, a is a list item. Also, yes i have tried value="Approve/@(a.Id)" and it has displayed the exact same thing.

Comment: OK. Another way you could try: `<button type="submit" ...>Approve/@a.Id</button>`? Obviously, including your other attributes in the `button` as before.

Comment: How about `value="@("Approve" + a.Id)"`?